# How to invoke union in rails 5.2 without delegating to Arel

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In rails 5.0 I could write a query

```
class DC < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :b_elements, through: :c_node
  has_many :d_elements, through: :e_node

  def both
    union = b_elements.union(d_elements)
    elements = Element.arel_table
    Element.from(elements.create_table_alias(union, :elements))
  end
end
```

When I upgrade to rails 5.2 I get deprecation errors:

DEPRECATION WARNING: Delegating union to arel is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.0. (called from both at ...)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Delegating ast to arel is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.0. (called from both at ...)

What is the proper way to call a union/intersect in Rails 5.2

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#arel`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/arel) method to explicitly use arel objects instead of AR Relations:

```
  def both
    union = b_elements.arel.union(d_elements.arel)
    elements = Element.arel_table
    Element.from(elements.create_table_alias(union, :elements))
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced up the same problem and found, that now the only way is to write everything in the most explicit way. Here is the example

```
c=Company.arel_table
request = c.project('*').where(c[:name].eq 'foo').union(
          c.project('*').where(c[:name].eq 'bar'))
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all request.to_sql
```